# Is that floating bottom bar a custom view?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I figure out that Google Drive has a new floating bottom bar when pressing long click on an item:

Is that bar a custom view developed just for Google Drive App or is it something new standard of Android?

I got same request from my designer and I would like to know how to do it.

[image: Floating bottom bar]

Comment: it looks like you can do it with a cardview and a relative layout

Comment: @njzk2 Do you have a link or any documentation of how to do it ? This bar can be swiped off the screen and it'll be dismissed.

Comment: may be as a custom view for a snackbar, to get the dismiss functionality, and to have it work with a coordinator layout?